# Photon Wave Function in Position Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Last year I did some research on the possibility of defining a PWF ( photon wave function) however there are many things that I haven't understood since then. So I want to ask what are your toughts on the next topics:

1. One can define the PWF in position space through a superposition of the momentum space PWF, however there's no position operator for the PWF.  In what sense is the PWF a valid wave function?
2. The PWF equations closely resemble the complex Maxwell equations (vacuum, no sources). Are the PWF fields related to the physical fields E and B?